# Glittering canvases

Tags: canvas

I am wanting to start creating and selling glittered canvases.
I have brought diamond dust, which I have applied to a canvas, it looks glittery and sparkling, (applied mod podge for the glue and gloss look ) 
but I think the dust looks a bit big grade cut/chunky.
Can anyone advise on what they use on canvases and what you do to yours?

Comment: Williamsy, welcome to the site! I edited your post (no need to say "thanks", for example) and formatted it a bit. Hint: if you want a new line, add *two* blank spaces before hitting return. For a new paragraph. *two* returns are the way to go. While you are waiting for answers, I suggest you take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn a lot more about how this site and the Stack Exchange system in general works.

Comment: If you could include a picture and perhaps any information on the products you used it can mean a great deal in getting a more accurate answer. While you do not have the reputation to embed a picture yet someone will be able to help with that as long as you supply a link .

Comment: I don't have a way to test right now, but I would think an answers lies along the path of a thin adhesive material (thick stuff could lead to clumping) applied to the canvas first, then apply the glitter/dust _evenly_ (maybe using a sifter), and after drying applying your sealant. If someone has the resources to try that out, feel free to steal this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just sprinkle glitter on mine, while the paint (usually oil, but could be acrylic) is still wet. Shake it later so the loose bits fly off. When dry consider using hair spray as a first fix, then you can varnish if you wish.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, Iv managed to done he canvas but just have trouble sealing it without any of it falling off.  The sealant zpray works wonders on my glitter glasses that I do, it seals it without any issues, but as the diamond dust is small pieces of glass, it's not sealing it properly. I will keep browsing around. But many thanks for the helpful Information x

Comment: Hey Williamsy, try using hairspray! To fix on top of the glitter. It will probably be enough to hold it, without spoiling its appearsnce. I use hairspray a lot, on my charcoal drawings too. Try on a small area first. I buy the pump action inexpensive ones. Not to close, not too much - dont make the whole thing wet - as dyes in glitter can run. Layer by layer and lightly. Let it dry a bit between coats. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: The other way, is let your paint dry fully. Then apply white pva glue (white glue, school glue) that you've watered down about 50:50 with water (or can be a bit thinner) paint that over the painting, (it will be transparent but a bit shiny when dry) sprinkle your glitter on when still wet. That should hold it!  You could also try painting thin pva on the canvas you've done, then add a bit more glitter on top. Finish with hairspray when dry.

Answer (score 1):

If your diamond dust is being displaced by the force of the spray varnish, then I'd suggest either

1. Applying the diamond dust to wet paint or
2. Applying the diamond dust to the varnish before it dries and then varnishing over it again once it's dried.

Answer (score 1):

I've used iridescent acrylic medium, which contains titanium coated mica flakes (source:https://images.utrechtart.com/Content/pdf/experts_archive/history/HS_utrecht_guide.pdf) for producing a pearl-like shimmer. You can mix it in with other acrylic paints, or apply a thin layer over dry paint. The mica flakes are fine enough such that they don't interfere much with the paint texture.